# Listing a count of unique values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which has fields to allow users to log different aircraft they see, inlcuding type, registratio, date, location etc. What I want to do is create a query which counts up all the different unique values under the 'type' field and adds them up so users can see how many different 'types' (of aircraft) they have seen. I used the following query;

```
SELECT `type`,COUNT(*) as count 
FROM `spotted_list` 
GROUP BY type  
ORDER BY count DESC
```

which works perfectly for the whole database producing results like this;

```
type            count Descending
B.737-800   802
AIRBUS A320 781
Boeing 737-800  716
A'bus A320  463
A330-200    371
```

but I want to filter that buy 'username' so I tried this;

```
SELECT `type`,COUNT(*) as count 
FROM `spotted_list` 
GROUP BY type 
ORDER BY count DESC 
WHERE `username` LIKE 'admin'
```

so hopeing that would display the above count list but only for the user called 'admin' however this is what i get;

Error
SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT  `type` , COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM  `spotted_list` 
GROUP BY TYPE 
ORDER BY count DESC 
WHERE  `username` LIKE  'admin'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `username` LIKE 'admin'
>   LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Does anyone know what is wrong please??

Answer (score 1):

The `where` should come before the `group by`:

```
SELECT  `type` , COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM  `spotted_list` 
WHERE  `username` LIKE  'admin'
GROUP BY TYPE ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: @user3717671: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the keywords is fixed. It is

```
select
from
join
where
group by
having
order by 
limit
```